# Slice within a slice golang

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to make a slice within a slice in golang, but have been unsuccessful. Here is my code snippet:

```
Slice1 := []string{"a","b","c"}
Slice2 := []string{"x","y","z"}
SliceOfSlices := []string{Slice1,Slice2}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/-ECPRTS0_X

Gives me the error : `cannot use Slice1 (type []string) as type string in array or slice literal`

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a set of square brackets:

```
SliceOfSlices := [][]string{Slice1, Slice2}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Slice1` and `Slice2` are of type `[]string`, so a slice of those will be a `[][]string`

http://play.golang.org/p/FPS5r5qbfO

```
Slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
Slice2 := []string{"x", "y", "z"}
SliceOfSlices := [][]string{Slice1, Slice2}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you have to add a square brackets like the following example:

```
Slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
Slice2 := []string{"x", "y", "z"}
SliceOfSlices := [][]string{Slice1, Slice2}
```

If you do not know the length of SliceOfSlices, you can also use the following approach:

```
SliceOfSlices := make([][]string, 0)
Slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
Slice2 := []string{"x", "y", "z"}
Slice3 := []string{"w", "w", "w"}
SliceOfSlices = append(SliceOfSlices, Slice1, Slice2, Slice3)
```